# Pigeonhole Principle : $mn+1$ pigeons into $n$ holes.

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle, extremal-combinatorics

If you have to put $n+1$ pigeons into $n$ holes, according to Pigeonhole principle, you will have to put two pigeons into the same hole. But what if you have to put $mn+1$ pigeons into $n$ holes?

(Does this mean that $m+1$ pigeons will have to be placed into the same hole?)

Comment: Yes this is the definition.

Comment: Hint: $ $ if not, then each hole has $\le m\,$ so the total is $\le \ldots ,$ contradiction.

Comment: You are correct.  Think about how many pigeons can be squirreled away if at most $m$ can be placed in each hole.

Comment: But why is it m+1? I don't understand what math brings you this

Comment: Ok. Think about it like this. What if you put a number of pigeons less than $m+1$ in each hole? Do you have some remaining pigeons?

Comment: If I have $n$ holes and precisely $nm$ pigeons.  I can place exactly $m$ pigeons in each hole (with no hole having $m+1$ or more).  But once I add one more pigeon, at least one of the holes will have $m+1$ pigeons, hence "with $nm+1$ pigeons in $n$ holes, there will be at least one hole with $m+1$ pigeons"

Comment: The principle assumes whole numbers of pigeons in each hole.  So anything more than $m$ must be at least $m+1$ pigeons.

Comment: Ok I got it now! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you have to put at least $m+1$ pigeons into one hole.**

Proof is by contradiction:

> Suppose not, so every hole contains at most $m$ pigeons. In that case there are at most $mn < mn+1$ pigeons across the $n$ holes, contradiction.

But we can find a distribution such that no hole contains $m+2$ pigeons:

> Put $m+1$ pigeons in the first hole, then $m$ pigeons in the subsequent $(n-1)$-holes. Then there are $m+1+(n-1)m = nm+1$ pigeons in total (as required), but no hole contains $m+2$ pigeons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right. You will have to put m+1 pigeons in one pigeonhole.

One easy way of solving basic pigeonhole principle questions is to divide the number of pigeons by number of pigeonholes and adding the reminder to the quotient.
Use it only for very basic questions.